# How do I upgrade R 3.1.2 to 3.2 through R studio?

Tags: r

I am using R studio in linux machine. I need to upgrade R version 3.2 (the latest version) from 3.1.2. 
I need an upgrade because I was trying to install a package, but gave me this error:

```
Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.5), ?biocLite for help
A new version of Bioconductor is available after installing the most recent version of R; see http://bioconductor.org/install
```

Comment: Why do you have to do it through RStudio?

Comment: Not sure exactly how to do it..

Comment: What linux OS are you on?

Comment: Doesn't RStudio check for a new version every time it starts?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty tahr).

Comment: Go to www.r-project.org and download R to the Ubuntu Software Center.  Then go into the Software Center to install it.

Comment: @thelatemail  Doesn't look like it updates/upgrades the version.

Comment: @RichardScriven Do I need to uninstall the older version first?

Comment: No, it will be replaced.  But it might be a good idea to do `sudo apt-get autoremove` afterward

Comment: Follow these instructions: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: @Dason- What's up with this? Installation error:
linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The best thing is to go to the command line (not the one inside RStudio) and use get-apt.Then you can also update RStudio while your are there. Also when I did this recently I had some problems related to rcpp but they were also easily solved by using the command line instead of updating packages from within R/RStudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the excellent [README for Ubuntu at CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu) and follow the steps outlined therein.

You have to do this at the command-line, ie in a terminal -- NOT in RStudio.

We support all this on a dedicated mailing list [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) which you can also [peruse via gmane](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.debian).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily *have to* be done at the command line, does it?  I've updated R a couple of times through Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: *If and only if* you added the additional repository for which you still have to read the README I listed.  After that a couple of methods are equivalent.  The software center is the least transparent but prettiest. Take your pick.